# I need the time difference between two times in minutes, and i want the result to be grouped by the difference and number of count

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have a table called Order_Timing with 2 cloumns named StartTime and EndTime as Shown below. I would like to get the difference in minutes and the count.

| start time | End Time |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-14 09:28:42.250 | 2022-03-14 09:29:23.693 |
| 2022-03-14 09:28:42.250 | 2022-03-14 09:30:40.150 |
| 2022-03-14 09:37:59.577 | 2022-03-14 09:38:04.730 |
| 2022-03-14 09:38:26.097 | 2022-03-14 09:38:38.583 |

Below is my expected result

| Minutes | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 - 1 mins | 1 |
| 1 - 2 mins | 2 |
| 2 - 3 mins | 1 |

Comment: Please share the code which you tried.

Comment: SELECT StartTime, EndTime, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime , EndTime) AS Minute
FROM Order_Timing. But this code does not give a count as stated in my initial result i wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(diff) 
from (select datediff(minute,start,enddate) as diff from [table])a 
group by diff
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the count by grouping the Minute Difference value which you have obtained in your query.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN minute_diff = 0
            THEN '0-1 min'
        WHEN minute_diff = 1
            THEN '1-2 min'
        WHEN minute_diff = 2
            THEN '2-3 min'
        END AS Minutes
    ,count(*) AS [count]
FROM (
    SELECT [start time]
        ,[end time]
        ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [start time], [end time]) AS minute_diff
    FROM Order_Timing
    ) a
GROUP BY minute_diff
ORDER BY 1
```

You can tweak the case statement as per your need.

Comment: This really solved my problem but what if i want to add another column which will be in percentage of the count e.g | Minutes | Count | % |

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37303779/sql-calculate-percentage-on-countcolumn It will help you to achieve it